# Is there any way to get byte data from android camera2 for each frame?

Tags: android

As per old camera api by following the below code.

```
mCameraInstance.camera.addCallbackBuffer(imageBuffer);<br>
mCameraInstance.camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
   @Override
   public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      processData(data);
      if (mCameraInstance != null)
            mCameraInstance.camera.addCallbackBuffer(imageBuffer);
      }
   });
```

I can get byte data each sec for every frame by using the above code. Is there any way to achieve this functionality in android camera2api.
Is there any way to achieve the similar funtionality in android 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing Camera2 preview frames returns empty buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147246/capturing-camera2-preview-frames-returns-empty-buffer)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would probably be to use an `ImageReader` hooked to the camera device. Attach an `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener` and get new images as they arrive. You can get the `Plane[]` image data and process it according to the format.